# Ошибка mix.js() is missing required parameter

Tags: node.js, laravel, vue.js

Я использую laravel-mix для работы с VUE, но недавно появилась ошибка mix.js() is missing required parameter при запуске команды npm run watch.

Вот полный текст ошибки.

```
# npm run watch

> watch
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --p                                                                                                              rogress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

^[[A/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Assert.js                                                                                                              :13:9)
    at JavaScript.register (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/c                                                                                                              omponents/JavaScript.js:40:16)
    at Api.mix.<computed> [as vue] (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-m                                                                                                              ix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:98:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/webpack.mix.js:7:58)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/                                                                                                              webpack.config.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils                                                                                                              /convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/c                                                                                                              onvert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:                                                                                                              123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/                                                                                                              convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules                                                                                                              /yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cl                                                                                                              i.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
root@654404-vds-admiralbub:/var/www/html/growex2# cd /var/www/html/growex2
root@654404-vds-admiralbub:/var/www/html/growex2# npm run watch

> watch
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --p                                                                                                              rogress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Assert.js                                                                                                              :13:9)
    at JavaScript.register (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/c                                                                                                              omponents/JavaScript.js:40:16)
    at Api.mix.<computed> [as vue] (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-m                                                                                                              ix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:98:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/webpack.mix.js:7:58)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/                                                                                                              webpack.config.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils                                                                                                              /convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/c                                                                                                              onvert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:                                                                                                              123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/                                                                                                              convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules                                                                                                              /yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cl                                                                                                              i.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
root@654404-vds-admiralbub:/var/www/html/growex2# npm run watch

> watch
> cross-env NODE_ENV=development node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js --watch --p                                                                                                              rogress --hide-modules --config=node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/webpack.config.js

/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:93
                                throw err;
                                ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: mix.js() is missing required parameter 1: entry
    at Function.js (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/Assert.js                                                                                                              :13:9)
    at JavaScript.register (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/src/c                                                                                                              omponents/JavaScript.js:40:16)
    at Api.mix.<computed> [as vue] (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-m                                                                                                              ix/src/components/ComponentFactory.js:98:53)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/webpack.mix.js:7:58)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/laravel-mix/setup/                                                                                                              webpack.config.js:12:1)
    at Module._compile (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-c                                                                                                              ompile-cache.js:192:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1098:19)
    at require (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/v8-compile-cache/v8-compile-c                                                                                                              ache.js:159:20)
    at WEBPACK_OPTIONS (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils                                                                                                              /convert-argv.js:114:13)
    at requireConfig (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/c                                                                                                              onvert-argv.js:116:6)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/convert-argv.js:                                                                                                              123:17
    at Array.forEach (<anonymous>)
    at module.exports (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/utils/                                                                                                              convert-argv.js:121:15)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:71:45
    at Object.parse (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/node_modules                                                                                                              /yargs/yargs.js:576:18)
    at /var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cli.js:49:8
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/www/html/growex2/node_modules/webpack-cli/bin/cl                                                                                                              i.js:366:3)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1196:14)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1250:10)
    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1074:32)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:909:12) {
  generatedMessage: false,
  code: 'ERR_ASSERTION',
  actual: false,
  expected: true,
  operator: '=='
}
```